# How to best pull off nested clickable elements?

Tags: html, css, nested, hyperlink

I have a situation that looks something like this

```
<div class="x" href="foo">
    <div class="y" href="bar"></div>
    <div class="z"></div>
    <div class="y" href="baz"></div>
    <a href="#">fooz</a>
</div>
```

`x` is a badge that should be clickable. The problem is that the badge also contains links that also should be clickable. In addition `y` and `z` are clickable. Unfortunately clicking the child links only leads to the outter `x` being pressed. How should I best handle something like this?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your situation - could you please provide an example somewhere, ie. on jsfiddle?

Comment: <a> tags should not be nested, it is not standard practice or valid and this is why you may be experiencing problems. It actually works in my browser (Chrome 14) but that's not to say it will work in every browser. Is there not a different way of coding your scenario which will remove the need for embedding <a> tags, then it will almost certainly work and if not we can debug more easily as it's something which should be working

Comment: I just used `a` elements to show that they are clickable elements. I didn't know nested links were invalid, but my problem is really about nested clickable block elements. I'll edit the question

Comment: Okay to check, is this a close enough representation of your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/7yzxQ/9/ With this I get a problem where if the <a> links are clicked, it also triggers the alert on the div behind which presumably you don't want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my previous comment (assuming my understanding of your scenario was correct), here is your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/7yzxQ/12/

It involves using stopPropagation to prevent the click being detected up the tree structure http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work and it's not valid html, because nested `a`-elements are not allowed. For a solution more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should not place `<a>` tags into another `<a>`. The solution here would be either using javascript, and event bubbling or you should separate the links and place/style them in a way where you see one integral badge. In the html you would actually build it from separated elements.

Personally I would go for the javascript way, as it is much more straightforward.